# How to sound alert in Rails console on exception/completion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alert, rails-console

Sometimes I run scripts through the rails console that take a long time to run. Is there a way to create some kind of alert (play a sound) whenever the script runs into an exception or is finished running? Idea here is to allow me to do other stuff and then come back if anything requires my attention.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Audite - a portable mp3 player in Ruby](http://www.matthias-georgi.de/audite/)

**API Example**

```
require 'audite'

player = Audite.new

player.events.on(:complete) do
  exit
end

player.events.on(:level) do |level|
  puts level
end

player.events.on(:position_change) do |pos|
  puts pos
end

player.load('test.mp3')
player.start_stream
player.forward(20)
```

**OSX Install**

```
brew install portaudio
brew install mpg123

gem install audite
```

**Debian / Ubuntu Install**

```
apt-get install libportaudiocpp0 portaudio19-dev libmpg123-dev
gem install audite
```